# Modeling 2 threads using UPPAAL

Tags: modeling, uppaal

Pseudo code that I am trying to model (has 2 threads) :-

```
sleep_time = 10;
deadline_time = 2;
```

main thread :-

```
while(true){
write(); // function is defined.
sleep(sleep_time);
}
```

thread-2 :-

```
while(true){
if(write function is called every 2 (deadline_time) secs){
} 
else {
callback_function();
}
}
```

Below are the automaton that I have built (and it's satisfying both the cases where when sleep_time > deadline_time I move to unsafe_state otherwise I never move to unsafe_state), but the issue I am facing I am not faithful to the actual code.

I am making use of the channel synchronization which kind of feels like I established some kind dependency between the 2 threads but in the actual code there is no such thing. I want to model it without creating this dependency (not using channel synchronization between them).

Edit :-

Automata for main-thread :-
[image]

Automata for thread-2 :-
[image]

Declarations :-

[image]

Comment: Please add a concrete minimal example (two automata) to your question. Sounds a bit like there is a fundamental misunderstanding, but I cannot say for sure without the example.

Comment: Sure. I have added the automata figures that I am modelling and the logic of enqueue and dequeuing. The problem is like I said above when I am performing verification on whether I will be reaching unsafe state. The property is getting satisfied because even thought the guard condition is True, it's executing/simulating the Thread-1 automata, thus satisfying the property of reaching unsafe-state for the Thread-2 automata.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The example is neither minimal nor complete. Also, *"like I said ..."* confused me. I cannot see the unsafe state being mentioned in the original question. Sorry... this is too vague for me. All I can say is: The actions on the edges (blue text) are atomic. If you want to model more interleavings of parallel threads, you have to split edges with multiple actions into multiple sequential edges having only a single action each. But that won't make the system safe. If a unsafe state was already reachable with grouped actions, it will still be reachable afterwards.

Comment: So what is the issue exactly? Do you get an error? Unexpected behavior?
Note that you can't just "add a clock value to an array", because timed automata cannot read clocks (they can only compare). Uppaal implements clock assignment to another clock, so your array should be an array of clocks. But that is a huge overkill for such a simple example. I suspect it can be simpler.
You mentioned synchronization -- yes, channel synchronization can simplify a lot of things, but it is not clear what behavior you need or expect.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have re-written the entire thing. @mariusm Can you please look into it. I basically want to achieve without the use of the chan synchornization between the automaton.

Comment: 1) when you are modeling a timeout, you need to add an invariant (locations Sleep and event_found) to force the automaton to leave the location as soon as the time out lapses. 2) consider using synchronisation instead of asynchronous wait for variable changes

Comment: For sleep atleast I agree that it should have been invariant instead of guard condition but I am not sure why it should be for the case of event_found. Coming to second point, I am exactly doing the sync using channels right. I want to avoid it. Is it not possible?

Comment: @MetaOverflow you are right about `event_found`, I overlooked that the outgoing edges have input synchronizations. Synchronizations are actually the best method to synchronize several processes immediately, but if you are looking for alternatives, then processes may communicate asynchronously through shared variables, which is wasteful in terms of time, memory and state space -- use them only if you really need them.